# Jest ->Property 'compile' does not exist on type 'OverrideBy'

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

I am working on a **Nest JS** project.I would like to write unit test for Nest JS using **jest**. In my actual controller, i have used **@UseFilters** annotation.So i have to include filter on my test controller as well.Here is the code.

This is my controller code

```
@Controller({ path: 'path', version: '1' })
@UseFilters(new AppErrorExceptionFilter())
export class MyController {
    constructor(private readonly MyService: MYService) {}

    @Post('data')
    public async lsitData(
        @Body() requestBody: RequestDto
    ) {
        return this.myService.listData(requestBody)
    }
}
```

This is my test controller

```
describe('MyController',()=>{
        let myController:MyController;
        let myService:MyService;
        beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
          controllers: [MyController],
          providers: [MyService],
        }).overrideFilter(AppErrorExceptionFilter).compile()
    
       myController = module.get<MyController>(MyController);
        myService = module.get<MyService>(MyService);
      });
    )}
```

This code gives below error

```
Property 'compile' does not exist on type 'OverrideBy'.ts(2339)
any
```

This is my nestjs version version **"@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0"**.

This is the first time i am writing test cases using jest.So am not aware about the syntax of the testing. I am not sure where I am doing mistake or whether there is other way to handle this.

Kindly please have a look on this issue.I spend too much time on this.

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** In NestJS version 9.0.0 and above, the .compile() method has been removed from the TestingModuleBuilder. You no longer need to call .compile() explicitly; the module creation itself compiles everything.

Answer (score 1):

When using **overrideFilter** you need to provide what is going to be used instead, e.g:

- useClass: you supply a class that will be instantiated to provide the
  instance to override the object (provider, guard, etc.).
- useValue: you supply an instance that will override the object.
- useFactory: you supply a function that returns an instance that will override the object.

So your code is missing one of the above, before **compile()**.